# shifting result using <<

Tags: python

[image]I want to calculate the string value that is return from a function, which is a hex value in string type. I used int(,16) to convert it to int, but I still cannot use the shift operator, any reason why?

```
       reg_dic= { "REG_RX_PKT_CNT_L_ADDR":"00000", 
               "REG_RX_PKT_CNT_H_ADDR":"00001", 
               "REG_RX_PKT_CNT_B_L_ADDR":"0001F", 
               "REG_RX_PKT_CNT_B_H_ADDR":"00020"
                 }
result_l, value_low = self.check_regs(portnum, list(reg_dic.values())[pair])
result_h, value_high = self.check_regs(portnum,list(reg_dic.values())[pair+1])
value_low = int(value_low, 16)
value_high = int(value_high, 16)
print(type(value_low))
value = value_high << 18 + value_low
print(list(reg_dic.keys())[pair], value_low)
print(list(reg_dic.keys())[pair+1], value_high)
print("Counter Sum is:",  hex(value))
```

Result I got is bunch of 0 and I have to break it.

Thanks in adv
[image]

Comment: `value_high` is a `str` object, if you look two lines above, you do `value_hight = int(value_high, 16)` which I think is a typo meant to do `value_high = int(value_high, 16)`

Comment: You have now changed your code, and the code you now have does not fail.  That's not the right way to deal with a question.  You should accept the answer that solved the problem.  And do not rewrite your question to an entirely different question.  Please make another.

Comment: @TimRoberts OK, SURE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NEW problem is one of precedence.  `+` has higher precedence than `<<` so your statement is parsed like `value = value_high << (18 + value_low)`.

To solve this, add parentheses explicitly, like: `value = (value_high << 18) + value_low`.

Answer (score 0):

`value = value_high << 18 + value_low` should be `value = value_hight << 18 + value_low` value_high is still a string. `value_hight` is the one you casted to int